# Kerberos constrained delegation using krb5 libs fails with error message GSS_S_BAD_MECH

Tags: c, unix, authentication, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I am trying to implement Kerberos Constrained delegation on a Unix system using krb5 libraries.
The concept is that a "trusted" user would be able to get a kerberos ticket on behalf of another user in the system.
I am using this code as a base for my implementation:
http://fossies.org/dox/krb5-1.11.5/t__s4u_8c_source.html

At the moment, I am able to generate the ticket on behalf of the trusted user; the ticket seems to be accepted by the exchange server but there is a last step where the server sends a challenge back as described here and that unfortunately is failing for me:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4559 (see chapter 5 for example)

I receive the "Negotiate" tag from the server and I need to decode it:

```
       S: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
       S: WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate 749efa7b23409c20b92356
```

"The client will decode the gssapi-data, pass this into
Gss_Init_security_context, and return the new gssapi-data to the
server."

In order to do that, I decode (base64) the data after the "Negotiate" string and cast it to this structure:

```
struct gssapi_data {
    gss_ctx_id_t context_hdl;
    gss_name_t client_name;
    gss_cred_id_t delegated_cred_handle;
    void *mech_data;
```

};

Here is what I am doing with this data:

```
data = (struct gssapi_data*) k5_base64_decode(enc_gssapi_data + strlen("Negotiate "));

if (data == NULL)
{
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "Could not decode gssapi_data");
    return -1;
}


major = gss_init_sec_context(&minor,
                             data->delegated_cred_handle,
                             &(data->context_hdl),
                             data->client_name,
                             &(data->mech_data),
                             GSS_C_REPLAY_FLAG | GSS_C_SEQUENCE_FLAG,
                             GSS_C_INDEFINITE, GSS_C_NO_CHANNEL_BINDINGS,
                             GSS_C_NO_BUFFER, NULL, &kcd_ticket_desc, NULL,
                             &time_rec);
```

This fails with error message: GSS_S_BAD_MECH...

This seems to indicate that mech_data is wrong but I don't really understand why.
Any idea of what could be wrong?
Am I right to assume that I need to decode the token from the server, cast it to gss_api structure and then call gss_init_sec_context with this?

Thank you very much for your help.
If something is not clear, please ask and I will try to provide more details